# Problem when filtering datatable by dataview (with Concat Fields)

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have the sql syntax:

```
SELECT 
    FatoraID, 
    FatoraCode, 
    FatoraDate, 
    FatoraProduct, 
    FatoraQuan, 
    FatoraReso, 
    FatoraPurPrice, 
    FatoraPurTotal, 
    FatoraCustomer, 
    FatoraSalePrice, 
    FatoraDis,
    FatoraPlus,
    FatoraSaleTotal, 
    FatoraDriverType, 
    FatoraDriver, 
    FatoraDriverName, 
    FatoraCarNo, 
    FatoraDriverCost, 
    FatoraDriverCostTotal, 
    FatoraDriverCostPaid, 
    FatoraDone,
    ProductName,
        CONCAT(R.AccCode,' ',R.AccName) AS ResoName,
        CONCAT(C.AccCode,' ',C.AccName) AS CusName,
        CONCAT(D.AccCode,' ',D.AccName) AS DName 
    FROM tblfatora F 
        INNER JOIN tblproducts P ON
            P.ProductID = F.FatoraProduct
        INNER JOIN tblaccounts R ON
            R.AccID = F.FatoraReso
        INNER JOIN tblaccounts C ON
            C.AccID = F.FatoraCustomer
        LEFT JOIN tblaccounts D ON
            D.AccID = F.FatoraDriver
    ORDER BY FatoraDate
```

And in somewhere I use dataview to filter the datatable:

```
    xPub_Filter = ""
    xPub_Filter = Trim("FatoraID+ 
    FatoraCode+ 
    FatoraDate+ 
    FatoraDriverType+ 
    FatoraDriverName+ 
    FatoraCarNo+ 
    FatoraDriverCostPaid+ 
    FatoraDone+
    ProductName+
    ResoName+
    CusName+
    DName
    like '%" & Me.TxtS.Text & "%'")
```

And I fill the GridView with the result, the problem is the filter is working very well when I remove the next fields:

```
ProductName+
ResoName+
CusName+
DName
```

But with them it's not working.

Comment: Your Trim make sense here like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%'" not at the start ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the filer expression is not correct

You have to specify for every column a comparison and the sytax is sql like

```
    xPub_Filter = ""
    xPub_Filter = "FatoraID like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR 
                                FatoraCode like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR  
                                FatoraDate like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR  
                                FatoraDriverType like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR  
                                FatoraDriverName  like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR  
                                FatoraCarNo like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%'  OR  
                                FatoraDriverCostPaid like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%'  OR  
                                FatoraDone like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR 
                                ProductName like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR 
                                ResoName like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%' OR 
                                CusName like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%'  OR 
                                DName like '%" & Trim(Me.TxtS.Text) & "%'"
```

Comment: thank you dear, it's working but it gives me "cannot perform 'like' operation on system.int32 and system.string", how to chaneg your solution to solve it?

Comment: yes like is onlöy valid for text, but i can't see what kind of column  you have. so you should actually see what you you want and determine what you want to filter, but so you can write your correct filter. you know best what you want

Comment: thank you, I just want to convert "FatoraID" column to string.